# Ionic vue 3 the routes not navigate properly

Tags: ionic-framework, vue-router, vuejs3, ionic-vue

I got problem with my router

the router not navigate properly with tab2 and tab3 logout and redirect again to login

https://github.com/scarfaceshing/ionicvue-bug-vue-router

Comment: please share the relevant and the concerned parts of your code and keep that repository link for more details

Comment: code looks fine, need more detail to make sense of what is going on here

Comment: what i mean is.. when click login from /login path then when you choose tab2 or tab3. and click logout so will redirect to the /login. and login back. again. the vue-router is not redirect to the tab1.. and turns like some duplicate component